# Multiple if conditions between two unequal pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

Have the following DataFrames:

**site**

```
OfflineFrom   |   OfflineTo  |   ShiftDays   |   Site  |
--------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-02        2017-10-10             6   |       ID|
2017-10-13        2017-11-10             6   |       ID|
2017-11-15        2017-12-09             6   |       ID|
2017-10-03        2017-10-11             6   |       IN|
2017-10-03        2017-10-10             6   |       IN|
```

**holiday**

```
Holiday    |   SiteID  |
------------------------
2017-10-07 |         ID|
2017-10-08 |         ID|
2017-09-12 |         ID|
2017-10-08 |         IN|
```

Looking to get a logic such that if a site has a holiday, and it falls in between OfflineFrom and OfflineTo, a day should be subtracted from ShiftDays.

*Result expected is:*

```
OfflineFrom   |   OfflineTo  |   ShiftDays   |   Site  |
--------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-02        2017-10-10             4   |       ID|
2017-10-13        2017-11-10             6   |       ID|
2017-11-15        2017-12-09             6   |       ID|
2017-10-03        2017-10-11             6   |       IN|
2017-10-03        2017-10-10             5   |       IN|
```

Appreciate getting the code to do it... Thanks

Code used to run this and test is:

```
# Evaluate if Holiday by Site is within OfflineFrom and OfflineTo
# Subtract the holiday from ShiftDays if it is so
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, time

# Prepare site ID series
s1 = pd.Series('ID', index = range(3))
s2 = pd.Series('IN', index = range(2))

site = s1.append(s2, ignore_index=True)

# Prepare OfflineFrom and OfflineTo series with datetime
offf = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017],
                     'month': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                     'day': [2, 5, 10, 20, 25]})

offt = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017],
                     'month': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                     'day': [10, 10, 18, 23, 28]})

offf = pd.to_datetime(offf)
offt = pd.to_datetime(offt)

# Make a series with ShiftDays as 6
sd = pd.Series(6, index = range(5))

# Assemble all these to a single dataframe
site = pd.DataFrame({'Site': site, 'OfflineFrom': offf, 'OfflineTo': offt, 'ShiftDays': sd})

holiday = pd.DataFrame({'SiteID': ['ID', 'ID', 'IN'], 'Holiday': [datetime.strptime('07-09-2017','%d-%m-%Y'),
                                                                  datetime.strptime('12-09-2017','%d-%m-%Y'),
                                                                  datetime.strptime('08-09-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
                                                                 ]})

test = pd.DataFrame((holiday.Holiday[:, None] >= site.OfflineFrom.values)
                                   & (holiday.Holiday[:, None] <= site.OfflineTo.values))
x = (holiday.Holiday[:, None]);x
y = site.OfflineFrom.values; y
```

Comment: Does your result really match your input? If yes, I don't understand what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` broadcasting:

```
site.ShiftDays -= ((holiday.Holiday[:, None] >= site.OfflineFrom.values)
                   & (holiday.Holiday[:, None] <= site.OfflineTo.values) 
                   & (holiday.SiteID[:, None] == site.Site.values)).sum(axis=0)
```

I did not test the efficiency of this though...

Comment: this gives me a _ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects_

Comment: @reservoirinvest Maybe you forgot the `.values`? There is no Series comparison here, just bumpy array.

Comment: Fixed the numpy.values. Not working still. Tried to see what 
'test = pd.DataFrame((holiday.Holiday[:, None] >= site.OfflineFrom.values) & (holiday.Holiday[:, None] <= site.OfflineTo.values) & (holiday.SiteID[:, None] == site.Site.values)).sum(axis=0)'
...evaluates to. It gives zero values.

Comment: @reservoirinvest Maybe you have wrong column types in your data frames (for the dates), thus the comparison does not work as expected?

Comment: @reservoirinvest The code you poste does not match your example - In your code, all holidays are in September while all the sites are offline in October.

Comment: Ahh.... that was so stupid of me! Sorry. Can you pl let me know what ':' and 'None' are for in the array? And what is the significance of 'sum(axis=0)'? And documentation link is appreciated.

Comment: @reservoirinvest `:` is used for indexing, like in python, `:` means the whole array/list, see [numpy.indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html), adding `, None` (or `np.newaxis`, see the link thereafter) will add one dimension to the array (see [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)), typically `holiday.Holiday` is a 1D array of size 3, with `, None` it becomes a 3x1 array, then using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with `site.OfflineFrom` you get a 3x5 array.

Comment: @reservoirinvest Using `.sum(axis=0)` will sum the row, for each column, in the 3x5 array, giving you a 1D array of size 5. Since the values inside the array are `bool`, using `sum` will basically count the number of values that are `True`.